# How to costume datepicker just one week

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two calendars and only want to limit one week, when I chose the first calendar date 1 then output to the two will come out 7th.
I am using ui datepicker

```
function initWidget() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
       numberOfMonths: 1,
       showButtonPanel: true,
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

   $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`onSelect`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) callback like:

```
onSelect: function(date){
 var selectedDate = new Date(date);
 var targetDay = selectedDate.getDay() + 7;
 var targetDate = new Date().setDate(targetDay);
 $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", targetDate);
}
```